# Как подвинуть фиксированный блок при прокрутке каретки?

Tags: html, jquery, css

Есть два `div` блока:

```
<div id="head">Шляпа сайта</div>
<div class="comments"></div>
```

Этим двум блокам я дал следующие css параметры:

```
#head, .comments{
width:100%;
}
#head{
color:blue;
height:60px;
left:0;
position:absolute;
top:0;
}
.comments{
height:2000px;
left:0;
position:fixed;
top:60px;
}
```

Когда я тяну каретку вниз `#head` уходит вверх а `.comments` таки остаётся со значением `top:60px`. Мне нужно чтобы `.comments` вырастал тогда, когда `#head` уходит вверх. Как в Google+. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать.

Comment: вообще не понятно, что должно произойти...

Comment: Нужно чтобы блок .comments заполнял пустое место блока #head

Comment: Взгляните, пожалуйста, на эти две фотографии 1) https://pp.vk.me/c631725/v631725061/e75/7JqFQp0WgVU.jpg 2) https://pp.vk.me/c631725/v631725061/e7e/GSw_jO9rC60.jpg     На первой блок #head присудствует. На второй - нет. Так вот, нужно чтобы когда блок #head уходит вверх страницы, блок .comments продвигается вверх тем самым закрывая собой пустое пространство.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Возможно приблизительно это?](http://codepen.io/NeedHate/pen/zvVQJZ)

```
.wrapper {
  height: 300%;
  background: #fff;
 }

.head {
 background: #71816D;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
}
.comments {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 30px;
  background: #c0c0c0;
  text-align: center;
}
.sticked {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: 300ms;
  font-size: 80%;

}
```

И сам скрипт:

```
var distance = $('.comments').offset().top,
  $window = $(window);

$window.scroll(function() {
  var screenTop = $(document).scrollTop();
  $('.curpos').text(screenTop + 'px')
  if ($window.scrollTop() >= distance) {

    $('.comments').addClass('sticked')
  } else {
    $('.comments').removeClass('sticked')
  }
});
```

Comment: А можно ли узнать на сколько пикселей страничка ушла вверх?

Comment: Обновил пример. Если ответ на вопрос оказался верным, просьба пометить его как подходящий ответ.

Comment: Уже ближе но не ещо не то

Comment: Я немного переделал Ваш вариант, но плюсик и правильный ответ всеравно Вам так как именно Вы подтолкнули меня в правильную сторону.

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужно, чтобы `.comments` прокручивался, а не стоял на месте, то тут дело в `position:fixed`. Меняем `fixed` на `absolute` и ваша панелька поедет вверх.
Отступ у `.comments` останется `top:60px`.

Comment: Нет нет. Он должен быть fixed. Прокручивается он внутри, с помощью overflow:scrol-y. Мне просто нужно чтобы блок .comments, который fixed, при прокрутки  страницы вниз - вырос на 60рх вверх заполнив этим самым пустое место после блока #head